# I can't install the HomeBrew

Tags: homebrew

I tried to reinstall the HomeBrew but it refuse me

---

```
 Warning: The Ruby Homebrew installer is now deprecated and has been rewritten in
Bash. Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 502, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user MyMac to be an Administrator)!
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 502, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

---

What could I do next?

Comment: what cmd did u run to see this?

Comment: do you have xcode installed?

Comment: The `sudo` error is due (as the error says) to the file /etc/sudoers having the wrong owner. There are a number of possible solutions in [this Ask Different Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157772/sudo-etc-sudoers-is-owned-by-uid-501-should-be-0), although some of them won't work (at least without modification) on the latest versions of macOS.

Comment: The error message tells you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

worked for me, lmk the output with a screenshot if not.